# How to get and read the csv files in same order from a directory in python

Tags: python, csv

There is a directory record_output which contains some csv files always in an order like this:-

```
2014-07-18_01:00.csv
2014-07-18_01:15.csv
2014-07-18_01:30.csv
2014-07-18_01:45.csv
```

Here is my code snippet:-

```
def getFiles():
        os.chdir("record_output/")
        for files in glob.glob("*.csv"):
            print files
```

This gives me the output:-

```
2014-07-18_01:30.csv
2014-07-18_01:15.csv
2014-07-18_01:45.csv
2014-07-18_01:00.csv
```

Is there someway to sort and get them in exactly the same order as they are in the directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `sorted()`?

```
def getFiles():
        os.chdir("record_output/")
        for files in sorted(glob.glob("*.csv")):
            print files
```

Will output:

```
2014-07-18_01:00.csv
2014-07-18_01:15.csv
2014-07-18_01:30.csv
2014-07-18_01:45.csv
```